# Is there a standard format for what to encrypt as a digital signature?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

When sending a message encrypted with asymmetric encryption, e.g.

> Long long, very long message here. `// encrypted with recipents public key`
>
> Signed by John Doe `// encrypted with own private key`

Does one want to be consistent with their own digital signature? Is there a standard format, or a widly used convention for the signature part? Or even, are there any conventions or is it just completely random what each person wants to put there?

Edit:

I guess my question isn't meant to be about standards per se. Rather about conventions if one would send the example format message in an instant messenger or email for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55160012/is-there-a-standard-format-for-what-to-encrypt-as-a-digital-signature#comment97094593_55177924):

> First - the users signs with its private key, not encrypts.. Yes, but doesn't the signing mean encrypting a signature with your private key (so that anyone can check it with your public key), like in my example?

Though the answer to this comment is generally: *no*.

Cryptographic signatures can be constructed in quite a lot of different ways. In RSA, the signing operation resembles some elements of the encryption, but this is a coincidence.

For example, take some the Schnorr signature scheme for elliptic curves:

```
(In this example, G is a base point for some secure elliptic curve E.
 All variables between brackets are scalars modulo the order of E.)


Setup:
  Alice has a private key x (random).
  Bob has Alice's public key P_A = [x]G.

Alice signs a message m:
  k := random()
  Q := [k]G
  c := H(Q||P_A||m)
  r := k + c*x
  Alice outputs s := (Q, r)

Bob verifies s over m:
  c := H(Q||P_A||m)
  Check if [r]G == Q + [c]P_A
```

As you can see, there is no real notion of "encryption" here. It is *just* a protocol.

Answer (score 2):

First - the users signs with its private key, not encrypts..

And now to the topic:

There are several protocols to pass encrypted and signed data.

If you are using (web) services, you may have a look at WS-Security or [XML signature](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature)

If you are looking for a more generalised standard, you may search "CMS Cryptographic Message Syntax" or PKCS#7

As well there are tools specific protocols, such as using openssl, in-document signatures (pdf, word,..) ... which are not standards per se, but commonly used.

Comment: `First - the users signs with its private key, not encrypts..` Yes, but doesn't the signing mean encrypting a signature with your private key (so that anyone can check it with your public key), like in my example?

Comment: As far I know signing is a decrypting operation with the private key over hash and proper padding. That's why it is very unsafe to use the same key for signing and encryption without proper padding (very commonly separate keys are used)

Comment: so one wouldn't do it like in my example?

Comment: @ruohola it's ok, just don't mix signing and encryption, they are mathematically similar operations, but there are small (and important) differences. When not done properly, you may break the security of your solution. The question was over standards, so I suggested a few, though you did not specify other requirements or use case

Comment: My question wasn't meant to be about standards per se. Rather about convetions if one would send the example format message in an instant messenger or email for example.

Comment: @ruohola Then - [S/MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME) may be feasible for email, messaging apps are having their own protocols, usually based on the [Signal protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_Protocol).